# Página não carrega os elementos quando atualizo no Iônic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular, ionic2

Bem tenho um app com menu lateral onde a primeira página é a home, e ela carrega elementos assim que o usuário entra no app. Estou usando Iônic 2 e a comunicação está sendo feita via socket. Um detalhe é que os elementos não carregam quando atualizo, mas quando clico no botão de menu e volto os elementos carregam, alguém pode me ajudar?

segue código do componente:

```
export class HomePage{

  item: Array<{title: string, owner: string}>;
  eventsList: Event[]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public eventService: EventService,
              public platform: Platform) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.info('HomePage initializated');
    this.platform.ready().then( () => {

      this.eventService.getAllEvents().subscribe(
        events => {
          this.eventsList = events
          console.log(events)
        }, err => {
          console.log("ERROR!", err)
        }
      ) 

    })

  } 
}
```

aguardo resposta, e posso ajudar com outros perguntas. :)